# Wordpress - redirect to link with end trailing

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

My site doesn't work when you try to go to for example `www.domain.com/example` or `wwww.domain/example1/example2` but `www.domain.com/example/` and `www.domain.com` both works. I have tried editing `.htaccess` file but haven't come with a solution.

Here is my current WordPress default `.htaccess`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I would like to come with a solution that redirects those URLs to URLs with end trailing.

Answer (score 1):

Your .htaccess looks correct - have you tried in a new incognito browser window?

Comment: Yes, I have tried different browsers and devices. Thing that I found weird is that it doesn't direct to 404 but to completely white page.

Comment: Have you confirmed you have mod_rewrite enabled on the server?

Comment: WordPress Admin Panel => Settings => Permalinks
and check the Permalink Settings. Then in Common Settings, check the ending of the URL structure. Most likely you don't have the ending slash (/) there.

Comment: I have /%postname%/ there so can't be it

Comment: I have other wordpress sites on the same server and they work fine

Comment: check the other site`s .htaccess file permissions and owners - maybe this one has wrong permissions or something?

Comment: .htaccess is identical including file permissions in all my sites

Comment: What about this? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/white-pages-with-no-redirect/

Comment: I disabled plugin, cleared my cache, updated permalinks and used incognito window and even tried with a different device but didn't do anything. Still white pages. I have tried also to disable my other plugins but it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: I tried default theme but didn't work with that. I have the same theme on other site that works completely fine.

Comment: I've tried to disable all my plugins and changed to default theme and updated permalinks but still it gives white page when one doesn't use slash in the end of URL. Only exception is index where end trailing is not needed. Could someone come with a solution or is reinstalling site only chance?

Comment: Settings > General - what do you have in WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) ? Another question would be if you have a DNS provider like Cloudflare? What happens if you access the site via IP address?